# Testing the Network request with cypress

Tags: ajax, cypress, qnetworkrequest

I want to test the network request and assert the requested data with Cypress.

```
cy.intercept('POST', '*service=jobsSearch*').as('ajaxRequest')

cy.get(selectors.dataComponent('jobs')).find('button').click()

cy.wait('@ajaxRequest')

cy.get('@ajaxRequest').its('request.body').should('contain', 'jobApprenticeshipType=stelle')

cy.get('@ajaxRequest').its('results.body').should('contain', 'mailAlertSearchTerm=Handwerk & Produktion')
```

I can reach to `'request.body'` and assert the `'jobApprenticeshipType=stelle'`. However, I can not reach to `results.body` to assert `'mailAlertSearchTerm=Handwerk & Produktion'`. Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response has a key of `response` and not `results`. My *guess* is that your response looks something like...

```js
{
  "results": {
    ...
    "mailAlertSearchTerm": "foo"
    ...
  }
}
```

In which case, you'd want to reference it by something like this:

```js
cy.get('@ajaxRequest')
  .its('response.body')
  .should('contain', 'mailAlertSearchTerm=Handwerk & Produktion')
// or, more specifically using the JSON properties
cy.get('@ajaxRequest')
  .its('response.body.results.mailAlertSearchTerm')
  .should('contains', 'Handwerk & Produktion');
  })
```

You can see this if you just get the intercept and log the entire thing.

```js
cy.wait('@ajaxRequest')
  .get('@ajaxRequest')
  .then((data) => cy.log(data))
```